# Use mod_rewrite to remove .php extension and clean GET urls concurrently

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is what I've tried till now:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]{1})$
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /article/%1 [L]
```

Basically, the first set of rules converts the URLs from something.php to something.

The second set of rules is supposed to replace anything that has article.php?id=NUMBER in it into /article/NUMBER.

Apache reports:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable 
configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The second set of rules is supposed to replace anything that has article.php?id=NUMBER in it into /article/NUMBER.`

I believe you have rules reversed.

Try this code instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mellori/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /article\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ article/%1? [R=302,L]

# internally rewrites /article/123 to article.php?id=123
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# PHP hiding rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This kind of works... But not completely... Requested: `http://localhost/mellori/article.php?id=33` and got `http://localhost/opt/lampp/htdocs/mellori/article/33` which is a full path in my system, not from webroot (and thus it results in an object not found error)

Comment: Is this .htaccess located in DOCUMENT_ROOT or in some sub-dir?

Comment: The webroot is at /opt/lampp/htdocs/ and the .htaccess is located at /opt/lampp/htdocs/mellori

Comment: This seems to work well for me. However, how could this be modified to handle both `http://localhost/opt/lampp/htdocs/mellori/article/33` and `http://localhost/opt/lampp/htdocs/mellori/article/33/` (please note trailing `/`.

Comment: Make trailing slash optional here: `RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/?$`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure when you match against `^article\.php$` that it is from the actual request and not the URI that's been rewritten by the previous rule. So you can either append an ENV check for an internal redirect, or match against `%{THE_REQUEST}.

Your choice:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]{1})$
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /article/%1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+article\.php\?id=([0-9]{1})(\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1 [L]
```

Comment: Nope... I still get the redirect problem. This is my full .htaccess file, without the documents that work as error (404, 403 etc) handlers: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6386963/ Of course I restarted apache after editing the file and please note that the article.php file is under a subdirectory of webroot (let's call it 'subdir'), if this has anything to do with...