# mod_rewrite for removing .php extension is producing 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked up and tried 3 or 4 answers on SO for this and they are not working for me.

I have `dev.mydomain.com/pw/` and I want `dev.mydomain.com/pw/builder` to redirect to `dev.mydomain.com/pw/builder.php` etc.

I have tried several solutions including:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite) and:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848872/use-mod-rewrite-to-remove-php-extension-and-clean-get-urls-concurrently)

as well as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

that I have from other projects.

I have also tried manipulating the `RewriteBase` to various things, like `/` and `/pw/` to no effect.

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong/not doing?

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `/pw/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pw/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pw/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What URL do you see in browser when you get 404?

Comment: that's what gets converted. When I click a link to "builder.php" that's how it redirects me. If I type in /pw/builder it says 404.

Comment: What happens when you enter `dev.mydomain.com/pw/builder` in your browser?

Comment: Not Found The requested URL /dev/pw/builder was not found on this server.

Comment: So `dev.mydomain.com/pw/builder` is 404 and `dev.mydomain.com/pw/builder.php` loads fine?